# How to load HTML page in DIV of the same page when clicking the menu list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to convert an html5 example I saw from the web but I am having trouble making the href to load on the same page in the container section, instead of loading into a new page. 
I added a jquery script to override the default behaviour of the href and load it to the div but still doesn't seem to work. Below is my HTML and JS codes.

**INDEX.HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>MY PROJECT</title>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">

        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

      </head>

      <body>

            <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="overlay"></div>

            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
                    <li class="sidebar-brand">
                        <a href="#">
                           MY PROJECT
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Back to Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="1.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> HTML 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="2.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> HTML 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="3.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> HTML 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="4.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> HTML 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="5.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> HTML 5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="6.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> HTML 6</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i> ADVANCE <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Advance</li>
                        <li><a href="advance.html">chart mod a</a></li>

                      </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dropbox"></i> SLIDE SHOW MODE</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <div id="page-content-wrapper">
              <button type="button" class="hamburger is-closed animated fadeInLeft" data-toggle="offcanvas">
                <span class="hamb-top"></span>
                <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
                <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
              </button>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                            <h1 class="page-header">Reports Control</h1>  
                            <p class="lead">(BETA) </p>
                            <p>Use nav side bar to select report ...</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

        </div>
        <!-- /#wrapper -->
        <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**INDEX.JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
      overlay = $('.overlay'),
     isClosed = false;

    trigger.click(function () {
      hamburger_cross();      
    });

    function hamburger_cross() {

      if (isClosed == true) {          
        overlay.hide();
        trigger.removeClass('is-open');
        trigger.addClass('is-closed');
        isClosed = false;
      } else {   
        overlay.show();
        trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
        trigger.addClass('is-open');
        isClosed = true;
      }
  }

  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
  });

  $('#wrapper').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#page-content-wrapper').load(page);
  });

});
```

Comment: Not sure what issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#wrapper')` is a DIV not the anchor, means that there is no href attributes exist. Instead try used :

```
// $('#wrapper .nav a') - will look for <a> tag inside of wrapper div at the .nav element
$('#wrapper .nav a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#page-content-wrapper').load(page);
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but now when I click the menu it does nothing.
I also tried adding an ID to the container div and tried $('#containerid').load(page); but still its not working.

Comment: does the click handler triggered? try put alert inside click handle and see what happens

Comment: Now that I debugged it more carefully I noticed that your code was actually working and it was just my CSS somehow obscuring the view of  the called html's background. The original div is overriding/overlapping the background of the called html, but that is a new issue all together.  Thanks!  Do you mind where I can find more documentations or tutorials discussing calling elements nested inside a div like the '#wrapper .nav a' approach?

Comment: glad to hear that and you're welcome. `calling elements nested inside a div like the '#wrapper .nav a` -- if you know really well how css works, then  you're mastered already. As jquery selector is the same as css selector then

Comment: Oh just one last question related to it.  What if I want only specific hrefs inside the #wrapper like if I want to exclude one of them what do you think is the best approach since I couldnt just #wrapper .nav a

Comment: Better give anchor element the new custom class name for the exclude one. As example `<a class="not_this" href="#">`, then to select only element except the prev one is by using `$('#wrapper .nav a:not(".not_this")')`

Comment: Yes, you should have :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your event listener is bound to the `#wrapper` element which has no `href` attribute. Inside the event handler function, `$(this)` refers to the element the handler was bound to, so you need to listen to clicks on the individual `<a>` elements.

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#page-content-wrapper').load(page);
  });
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but now when I click the menu it does nothing. I also tried adding an ID to the container div and tried $('#containerid').load(page); but still its not working.